# Problemas con __dirname al crear un pdf con Nodejs en Heroku

Tags: nodejs, heroku

Me encuentro aprendiendo Nodejs, recientemente pude realizar un todo list con el motor ejs y generar un reporte pdf con su respectiva descarga, el problema es que al hacer el deploy el heroku y usar el método generarpdf hay un problema con encontrar la ruta para la creación del pdf, por lo cual me devuelve un json vacio, antes lo tenía configurado con la ruta de mi equipo, pero al usar la propiedad __dirname sigo con el mismo resultado, alguna idea de lo que pueda ser?

Nota especial: el programa funciona correctamente en modo localhost.

Adjunto código e imagen del servidor para que se entienda

```js
app.get('/generarPdf', function(req, res) {
    res.render('template', {actividades: actividades},(err, data) => {
        if(err){
        } 
        else 
        {
            let opciones = {
                'height': '11.25in',
                'width': '8.5in',
                'header': {
                    'height': '20mm',
                },
                'footer': {
                    'height': '20mm',
                },
            };
            //libreria html-pdf
            pdf.create(data, opciones).toFile(__dirname + '/reportes/reporte.pdf', (err, data) => {
                if(err){
                } else {
                    console.log('reporte creado con exito');
                    actividades = [];
                    res.redirect('/descargar');
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hmmm, y en vez de `__dirname` no podrías usar una ruta relativa: `./reportes/reporte.pdf`?

Comment: acabo de probar su sugerencia, aun así me retorna el json vacio :/

Comment: Por lo que entiendo de tu código, estás intentando crear un fichero programaticamente en el directorio desde donde se ejecuta tu script. ¿Has consultado si Heroku permite la creación de ficheros en ese directorio? Lo usual es configurar un directorio de acceso público para este tipo de situaciones, por temas de seguridad. Me parece que ese es el principal problema. Saludos

Comment: Favor de leer Cómo formular una buena pregunta

Comment: Mauricio, te comento, probé creando el directorio public para la generación de pdf, sin embargo no me funciono, me imagino que el problema al final consiste en que heroku no permite la creación de ficheros, sin embargo me resulta curioso ya que anteriormente hice una app para subir archivos y después visualizarlo, el cual también hice un deploy en heroku y funcionó perfectamente, tiene un parentesco similar ya que efectivamente se crea el directorio para almacenar el archivo, por ultimo igual pienso que el problema es la libreria.